# Create and Manage Upstart Services without Root Access

Tags: services, upstart

Is there anything like `~/.config/systemd/user/` and `systemctl --user start ...` for Upstart?

`initctl --user ...` required `UPSTART_SESSION` environment variable, looks like `--user` here has different meaning from `systemd`.

Answer (score 2):

It has indeed.  upstart has multiple *per-session* instances of itself, one per login session per user.  systemd has *per-user* instances of itself, one per user for that user in all contexts (and outwith any individual login session).

## Further reading

- ["Session Init"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init). *upstart Cookbook*. Ubuntu.
- James Hunt, Stéphane Graber, Dmitrijs Ledkovs, and Steve Langasek (2012-11-12). *[Ubuntu Raring upstart user sessions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/RaringUpstartUserSessions)*.    Ubuntu.
- Nathan Willis (2013-04-17). *[Upstart for user sessions](https://lwn.net/Articles/547422/)*.  LWN.
- [Why does running `killall init` as user log me out?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181480/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194208/5132

Comment: Adding on to this, to use Upstart as a session init one must invoke it as an unprivileged user, for example from xinitrc. Only the child processes will have the UPSTART_SESSION variable and be able to access the running instance via `initctl`.